# How to have a simple sticky position article list in a MySQL database that can be retrieved with only one query?

Tags: sql, mysql, position, rank

I have a paginated list of articles that needs to be sorted by rank but when an article has position <> 0 then it must be inserted in that specific position.
I thought that I can at least have the articles with the correct position extracted for the current page and then sort them in PHP to show then in the proper position.
I want to do this in MySQL with only one query

Some of my attempts are:

This query tries to select first the articles that have the correct position for the current page and then articles with the highest rank

```
SELECT id, rank_score, position
FROM Articles
ORDER BY ((position <= (50 * 1)) AND (position > 50 * (1-1))) DESC, rank_score DESC
LIMIT 0, 50
```

50 is the number of articles displayed on page and 1 is the current page number, they are added on query generation.

This query has the problem that on page 2 the results are wrong because by adding LIMIT 50,50 you can go beyond the articles that have a position on that page.

Another attempt:

```
SELECT (
    SELECT id, rank_score, position
      FROM Articles
  ORDER BY ((position <= (50 * 1)) AND (position > 50 * (1-1))) DESC, rank_score DESC  
     LIMIT 50)
UNION (
  SELECT id, rank_score, position
    FROM Articles
 ORDER BY rank_score DESC LIMIT x)
```

To work correctly the second query must have a limit equal to the number of rows returned from the first query.
Plus, anytime an article that has a very high rank that but also a very high position it will be shown earlier because position is ignored in the second query.

Answer (score 10):

Your first ORDER BY expression isn't needlessly complex enough. Try:

```
ORDER BY ((position < (50 * (1 + (1-1 * (50 / 1)))) 
    OR position = (50 + (50 - (50 * POW(50, 0)) * 1))) 
  AND (position > 50 * (1-1) / 1 * 50)) DESC
```

Alternately, just use:

```
ORDER BY (position <= 50 AND position > 0) DESC
```

I recommend complexifying (or, if you must, simplifying) the rest of your expressions as well. I predict you'll either find your problem, or open a hole into another universe, wherein the magical unicorns will solve your problem.

Comment: Sorry that I didn't simplify the expression, it's complex because offsets are generated from php, that is why you need multiplication by 1 which is the page number and substraction.
Unfortunately you didn't get the question you just stopped at the silly expression, also your magical unicorns didn't help.

Comment: @codeassembly: yeah, I got that. My point is, you're making this overly complicated and (apparently) getting confused as a result. Start *simple:* all you really want is a sort order that'll remain **consistent** regardless of which page you're asking for: the LIMIT will take care of the rest. You neglected to specify the variables in your expression, but that's irrelevant because you shouldn't have variables in that expression at all if you want paging to work...

Answer (score 1):

yeah, the magic unicorn is right, that query is wrong
here is the real magic query

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 rownum, IF(position=0,@rownum,position) as loc, a.id, a.rank_score, a.position
FROM (SELECT @rownum:=0) r, Articles a
ORDER BY rank_score DESC) t 
ORDER BY loc DESC
LIMIT 0, 50
```

Answer (score 0):

I found  the answer to the question.
I gave up on the sql + php sorting solution and found a full sql solution where I get all articles sorted by rank and position where available.

```
SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 rownum, IF(position=0,@rownum,position) as loc, a.id, a.rank_score, a.position
FROM (SELECT @rownum:=0) r, Articles a
ORDER BY  loc, rank_score DESC
LIMIT 0, 50
```

Answer (score 0):

one minor observation a magic unicorn could see in the last query - you're ordering the result set on a field (loc) that is based on another field (@rownum) which you expect to have values based on the sorted set. Mystical? Circular dependencies? Or just strange? ;-)